# How to speed up an apache webserver?

Tags: apache-httpd, optimization

We have a PC:

- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E7300  @ 2.66GHz
- 3 GByte RAM
- HDD: 160 GByte WD1600AAJS-08L7A0

And we have Ubuntu 12.04 on it with apache 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7. Serving just static HTML files (that are updated in every ~5 minutes..). Users auth via LDAP, and there is some php, but the php part isn't used much.

The daily distinct user base visiting the site is ~30. There are some scripts running on the PC, but not making any bigger load..

The problem: as the user base gets larger, the website seems to get slow when the user is opening up the webpage.

**Question:** How can we speed up the loading of the webpage?

Apache benchmark said this little server can serve twice as many users as it is using now.. but sometimes the apache get's slow.

workaround: a cronjob for stop; sync; start apache at lunchtime helped a little bit..

We don't have money for upgrading the physical machine, that is not an option :)

**UPDATE#1:** apache is only enabled via HTTPS!
**UPDATE#2:** We disabled the unneeded apache modules, any other idea? :)

Comment: It seems that your problem is related to the auth process...

Comment: hmm.. the users only log in once, that is OK(?), no slowness. The problem could occur if they opening the link when they are already authenticated. Sometimes the webpage loads slow then. network it 100 Mbit/sec, on a LAN

Answer (score 1):

I would setup Varnish in front of the web server (or another cache): 
https://www.varnish-cache.org/

I wrote a small blog post on Varnish 3 here:
http://aarvik.dk/varnish-cache-in-general-and-simple-static-files-configuration/

That would definitely help :-)

Comment: Many thanks! :) Still waiting if there are other answers.